# servletContext.getResource difference between Tomcat 7 and 8

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, tomcat8

```
getServletContext().getResource("/WEB-INF/test.xml")
```

this will return the following on tomcat 7

```
jndi:/localhost/TestWebApp/WEB-INF/test.xml
```

but on the tomcat 8 i get

```
file:/C:/Users/userName/Desktop/tomcat-8.0.33/webapps/TestWebApp/WEB-INF/test.xml
```

why does tomcat 8 behave differently from tomcat 7 for this method?

Comment: Could it be because they got rid of the apparently pointless `jndi:` namespace and used `file:` URLs directly?